# c# how to use Combobox.Value for a From Clause in a Sql query

Tags: c#, select, datagridview, combobox, oledb

Please can you assist me in a very weird request

I am building a form to represent a table in a datagridview. 
I want to change the data that is bound to the datagridview when i select a different value in a combobox. I bound the event to a button.

i get an error when i run the code:

### An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause.

the code i have is as follows.

```
 private void Ok_button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = E:\database.accdb; Persist Security Info =False;");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From  @name ", con); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", comboBox1.SelectedValue);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
        da.Fill(dt);
        dt.TableName = "Project";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

Comment: Change `comboBox1.ValueMember` to `comboBox1.SelectedValue`

Comment: thank you for the reply. i have made the change but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: You can't use the table name as an SQL Parameter

Comment: is there anyway i can change the datasource from a combobox?

Comment: The Risky String concatenation way.

Comment: It is not risky if you use a white-list. Define an array or dictionary in which the valid table names are stored. Use the combobox index or value to find the table name.

Comment: @SergeyL You're absolutely correct

Comment: @SouthAfricanGuy Please go through Last Updated coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will help you:

```
private void Ok_button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =        Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = E:\database.accdb; Persist Security Info =False;");
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Concat("Select * From ",comboBox1.Text), con); 


cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
da.Fill(dt);
dt.TableName = "Project";
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much this helped a lot. will play around to get it to do what i want but this puts me on the right track. would upvote but don't have the rep :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Data Bound Items then use comboBox1.SelectedValue. If you use Unbound Mode then use comboBox1.SelectedItem.

```
    private void Ok_button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = E:\database.accdb; Persist Security Info =False;");
        //OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From  " + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), con);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From  " + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dt.TableName = "Project";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

But not advice this way. You can use stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

you can not pass table name as parameter. you can build sql based on your value selection in your combobox. replace your code with this code and check.

```
private void Ok_button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =  Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = E:\database.accdb; Persist Security Info =False;");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Concat("Select * From ",comboBox1.SelectedValue), con); 


    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
    da.Fill(dt);
    dt.TableName = "Project";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
 private void Ok_button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = E:\database.accdb; Persist Security Info =False;");
     string tableName = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
     var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
     string escapedTableName = builder.QuoteIdentifier(tableName);
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From " + escapedTableName , con);        
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
     da.Fill(dt);
     dt.TableName = "Project";
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```